# Find row that has same value in one column over multiple rows while another column has different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Sorry I couldn't demonstrate this on SQLFiddle because it seems to be down when I asked this question.

I have the following table

```
Col1        Col2     
====        ====     
1           A       
1           A       
1           B    
2           C
2           C
```

If I run the group by query of

```
SELECT COL1,COL2
GROUPBY COL1,COL2
```

I would get

```
Col1        Col2     
====        ====     
1           A            
1           B    
2           C
```

My question is how can I write a query to detect column 1 value when I have more than one different values in column 2?  Essentially the return of that query should give me "1" because that is where the rows have the same value in Col1 while Col2 have different values over the span of multiple data rows.

Comment: Do you mean: return all Col1s that have 2 or more Col2 values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `group by` clause with `min()` and `max()` :

```
select col1
from table t
group by col1
having min(col2) <> max(col2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select Col1,count(distinct Col2) as [different Col2 value count]
from yourtable
GROUP BY COL1
having count(distinct Col2)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Col1 
       FROM table t1 
            JOIN table t2 
                  ON T1.col1 = T2.col1 AND T1.col2 != T2.col2
```